# Почему не работает метод Array.prototype.map()?

Tags: javascript

Пишу функцию, которая должна возвращать массив-"башенка", по типу

```
[
  "  *  ",
  " *** ", 
  "*****"
]
```

, где параметр функции `n` - это количество этажей данной "башни", т.е. количество элементов массива. В примере выше `n == 3`. Как видно каждый элемент массива - это строки, у которых одинаковая длина, но различное количество `*`, в зависимости от индекса массива.

```
function towerBuilder(n) {
        let arr = new Array(n);
        return arr.map(function(item, index, array) {
            let q = ( (1 + (array.length - 1) * 2) - (1 + 2 * index) ) / 2;
            return (' '.repeat(q) + '*'.repeat(1 + 2 * index) + ' '.repeat(q));
        })
    }
```

Функция возвращает массив с пустыми элементами.

Comment: Потому что в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#description) русским по белому написано «Функция callback вызывается только для индексов массива, имеющих присвоенные значения». В вашем `arr` нет ни одного значения.

Comment: @AlexeyTen понял, спасибо!